# Philips Hue - is it possible to press the button on the hue by code

Tags: web-services, philips-hue

I was wondering if it was possible to perform a webrequest to call the button which let you connect the phone with the hue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a way to address this physical button or link button. It isn't possible via the SDK's but you can use the API to do a PUT on

```
http://<ip-address.of.the.bridge>/api/<username>/config
```

with the following message/body

```
{
    "linkbutton": true
}
```

You still need to press the physical button at least once to generate a username that is linked with your device.

```
URL:  /api
messagebody:    {"devicetype":"my_hue_app#your_device_name"}
method:     POST
```

Comment: Doesn't work anymore, you get the error: "parameter, linkbutton, is not modifiable"

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not! A user needs **physical access** to ***both*** the phone and the bridge to establish a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this is a hard requirement by Philips. This is to prevent unrestricted users from controlling your lights.

Comment: There have been several security issues allowing unauthorised control of the lights, check out the drone hack for instance. Having a requirement to physically be there to press the button is obscurity not security.